# How should I interpret these lambda expressions?

Tags: .net, razor, entity-framework-6

I'm learning how to work with .net entity framework and one of the things the expressions that has confused me the most are ones that take this form:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.StudentCount
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In this particular example I understand that it is displaying the enrollment date for each item but I don't understand the modelItem on the left of the expression. From what I understand, that is meant to be the parameter passed into the function on the right side of the operator. However, it's not used on the right side so I'm having trouble understanding its significance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `DisplayFor` is a tricky extension. You've got to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx) to understand it.

There is no compiler or logical error as such. The given mark up would work fine if you only need to display the value of property EnrollmentDate for each item in the Model.

But here `DispalyFor` will not generate correct names for the controls. So, if it's only for display it's fine, but if you want to post the values of input elements as the Model, you have to make changes in your view.

You might want to read [this](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b1e0b153-47f4-4b29-8583-958aa22d9284.aspx) and [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx), to understand model binding better.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The [`DisplayFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) extension defined as :

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression  //pay attention to this part
)
```

That means, `DisplayFor()` receive an [`Experssion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) of specific signature as parameter. The signature is, that the expression need to have an **input parameter**, and a **return value**.

Now, speaking in the context of your sample code. Parameter of `DisplayFor` in your code reads as an "expression having an input parameter named `modelItem` and returning value of `item.EnrollmentDate`". So, `modelItem` in this case doesn't effect the output of the expression, but it need to be there to make your expression *recognized* as having an **input parameter**, hence considered complies with the signature.